# Haskell: sub-optimal parallel GC work balance, no speedup in parallel execution

Tags: multithreading, performance, haskell, ghc

The description of my problem is practically the same as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13551330/1809545), but although I think I can understand the corresponding [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13560127/1809545), I can not see how does it apply to my problem, if at all.

Here is my example program

```
{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}

import System.Random (randoms, mkStdGen)
import Control.Parallel.Strategies
import Control.DeepSeq (NFData)
import Data.List

data Point = Point !Double !Double

fmod :: Double -> Double -> Double
fmod a b | a < 0     = b - fmod (abs a) b 
         | otherwise = if a < b then a 
                        else let q = a / b 
                             in b * (q - fromIntegral (floor q :: Int))

standardMap :: Double -> Point -> Point
standardMap k (Point q p) = 
   Point (fmod (q + p) (2 * pi)) (fmod (p + k * sin(q)) (2 * pi))

iterate' gen !p = p : (iterate' gen $ gen p)

iterateN :: (Point -> Point) -> [Int] -> Point -> [Point]
iterateN _ [] p = [p]
iterateN gen (dn:dns) p = 
   p : (iterateN gen dns $ (head . drop dn) $ iterate' gen p) 

ensemble :: [Point]
ensemble = zipWith Point qs ps
   where qs = randoms (mkStdGen 42)
         ps = randoms (mkStdGen 21)

main = let dns = take 100 $ repeat 10000
           ens = take 1000 ensemble
           obs = \(Point p q) -> p^2 - q^2
           work = map obs . (iterateN (standardMap 7.0) dns)
           ps = parMap rdeepseq work ens
       in putStrLn $ show (foldl' (+) 0 $ map (foldl' (+) 0) ps)
```

the problem is that this program does not scale well with the number of threads.
For example, on `Debian 3.2.46-1 x86_64}` with `GHC 7.4.1` I get

```
$ ghc -O3 --make stmap.hs -threaded

$ time ./stmap +RTS -N1
  real    1m9.791s
  user    1m9.448s
  sys     0m0.208s

$ time ./stmap +RTS -N2
  real    0m36.981s
  user    1m13.113s
  sys     0m0.656s

$ time ./stmap +RTS -N4
  real    0m23.110s
  user    1m31.310s
  sys     0m0.792s

$ time ./stmap +RTS -N8
  real    0m20.537s
  user    2m21.921s
  sys     0m21.017s
```

This numbers may fluctuate a lot. The only indicator I have found of where the problem might be is the suboptimal parallel GC work balance, for example:

```
$ ./stmap +RTS -N8 -sstderr 1>/dev/null
112,032,905,392 bytes allocated in the heap
  59,112,296 bytes copied during GC
     971,520 bytes maximum residency (35 sample(s))
      96,416 bytes maximum slop
           8 MB total memory in use (1 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
Gen  0     27032 colls, 27031 par    6.49s    0.81s     0.0000s    0.0015s
Gen  1        35 colls,    35 par    0.39s    0.05s     0.0014s    0.0028s

Parallel GC work balance: 4.05 (6799831 / 1680927, ideal 8)

                     MUT time (elapsed)       GC time  (elapsed)
Task  0 (worker) :   14.81s    ( 14.84s)       0.96s    (  0.97s)
Task  1 (worker) :    0.00s    ( 15.81s)       0.00s    (  0.00s)
Task  2 (bound)  :    0.03s    ( 15.80s)       0.01s    (  0.01s)
Task  3 (worker) :   14.72s    ( 14.82s)       0.98s    (  0.99s)
Task  4 (worker) :   14.70s    ( 14.84s)       0.96s    (  0.97s)
Task  5 (worker) :   14.69s    ( 14.82s)       0.98s    (  0.99s)
Task  6 (worker) :   14.69s    ( 14.82s)       0.98s    (  0.99s)
Task  7 (worker) :   14.72s    ( 14.81s)       0.99s    (  1.00s)
Task  8 (worker) :   14.76s    ( 14.83s)       0.97s    (  0.98s)
Task  9 (worker) :   14.76s    ( 14.81s)       1.00s    (  1.00s)

SPARKS: 1000 (1000 converted, 0 overflowed, 0 dud, 0 GC'd, 0 fizzled)

INIT    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
MUT     time  118.87s  ( 14.95s elapsed)
GC      time    6.87s  (  0.86s elapsed)
EXIT    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
Total   time  125.74s  ( 15.81s elapsed)

Alloc rate    942,488,358 bytes per MUT second

Productivity  94.5% of total user, 751.8% of total elapsed

gc_alloc_block_sync: 1130880
whitehole_spin: 0
gen[0].sync: 0
gen[1].sync: 175
```

where it is ~4, but just in the next run it was much worse, ~2,

```
$ ./stmap +RTS -N8 -sstderr
60364.38698300099
 112,033,885,088 bytes allocated in the heap
  4,626,963,592 bytes copied during GC
   2,101,264 bytes maximum residency (1846 sample(s))
     652,528 bytes maximum slop
          13 MB total memory in use (0 MB lost due to fragmentation)

                                   Tot time (elapsed)  Avg pause  Max pause
Gen  0     25497 colls, 25496 par   29.42s    3.70s     0.0001s    0.0022s
Gen  1      1846 colls,  1846 par   17.97s    2.26s     0.0012s    0.0071s

Parallel GC work balance: 2.00 (577773617 / 288947149, ideal 8)

                    MUT time (elapsed)       GC time  (elapsed)
Task  0 (worker) :   14.86s    ( 15.03s)       6.07s    (  6.10s)
Task  1 (worker) :    0.00s    ( 21.13s)       0.00s    (  0.00s)
Task  2 (bound)  :    0.03s    ( 21.11s)       0.02s    (  0.02s)
Task  3 (worker) :   14.92s    ( 14.99s)       6.06s    (  6.14s)
Task  4 (worker) :   14.88s    ( 15.02s)       6.07s    (  6.11s)
Task  5 (worker) :   14.91s    ( 15.02s)       6.09s    (  6.12s)
Task  6 (worker) :   14.92s    ( 15.04s)       6.07s    (  6.10s)
Task  7 (worker) :   14.86s    ( 15.03s)       6.03s    (  6.11s)
Task  8 (worker) :   14.86s    ( 15.03s)       6.07s    (  6.10s)
Task  9 (worker) :   14.92s    ( 15.00s)       6.11s    (  6.13s)

SPARKS: 1000 (1000 converted, 0 overflowed, 0 dud, 0 GC'd, 0 fizzled)

INIT    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
MUT     time  120.36s  ( 15.18s elapsed)
GC      time   47.39s  (  5.96s elapsed)
EXIT    time    0.00s  (  0.00s elapsed)
Total   time  167.75s  ( 21.13s elapsed)

Alloc rate    930,821,901 bytes per MUT second

Productivity  71.7% of total user, 569.5% of total elapsed

gc_alloc_block_sync: 1253157 
whitehole_spin: 21
gen[0].sync: 4
gen[1].sync: 19789
```

What is responsible for these fluctuations in execution time? And most importantly, how can one improve the parallel GC work balance in my concrete example and in general?

Comment: Does it improve if you use `-qg1`? This will disable parallel collections for generation 0.

Comment: What does threadscope say?  It might give you some insight into whether you're effectively using your cores, which could give you a better speed up than worrying about the garbage collector.

Comment: @NathanHowell It does not improve anything probably. The problem is that I can not make a consistent measurement of the execution time as it fluctuates allot (for example, for -N8 case from 15s to 25s) independently of using -qg1 flag or not. I am wondering if somebody can reproduce this.

Comment: @bheklilr Sadly I am not able to use threadscope on the machine at the moment...

Comment: @BenjaminBatistic Windows then?  You can still run the program with profiling enabled, and then transfer the output files to a machine that can run threadscope, if you have one available.  It's a lot of work, I know, but it would be an option if you run out of other alternatives.

Comment: @bheklilr Not Windows, Debian server, with user permission,  with glib conflicting cabal install threadscope, ..., but yes, I will view the profiling output on my laptop, thank you.

Comment: I am trying to run your example but I get this error: D:\>ghc test.hs
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( test.hs, test.o )

test.hs:19:1: Parse error in pattern: iterate'

Comment: @AlexeyAlexandrov There was a mistake in `{-# LANGUAGE BangPatterns #-}`, try now, thank you.

Comment: what's your machine? are there other users using it or programs running in the background?

Comment: The machine has intel cpu i7-860, there were no unnecessary  processes running in the background at the time. But the truth is that I can not reproduce the behavior on a different machine: intel Q6600 (4 threads), Linux 3.10.6-2-ARCH, GHC 7.6.3, which confuses me a bit and makes me think that the problem might be elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

The varaition is likely due to the fact that using `+RTS -Nn` leads to creation of one bound thread and `n` worker threads (cf. the output), hence one worker will share a physical core with the bound thread and interfere. Hence, it is recommended to use a number lower then the total number of available physical cores as argument for `+RTS -N`.

Another potential issue is load balancing: you may need to split the work differently if there is load unbalance (threadscope profile would help). Have a look at this [paper](http://research.microsoft.com/pubs/80976/ghc-parallel-tuning2.pdf) for more details on tuning.